Does zsh support colours in RBUFFER?
I searched online and didn't find a clear answer (unless I'm missing some reference).
I've been trying this in my .zshrc:
local redCircle='\e[0;31m● \e[0m'
echo "$redCircle"
RBUFFER="$redCircle"

When I echo, it does indeed print a red circle. But when I set the RBUFFER, it doesn't.
Is this supported in zsh? If not, is there any other way to add some colours to the RBUFFER?

Out of curiosity -- does RBUFFER=$(printf '%b' "$redCircle") behave any differently? (It replaces the escape sequences with the literals they refer to).

you're right I edited it and removed the bash tag. no printf behaves the same

Bluntly, the behavior described seems reasonable -- the readline buffer is supposed to have user input, and it's not like a users are expected to manually type escape sequences. What's the behavior you're trying to achieve by populating RBUFFER thus? (I could see calling read with a prompt that's preceded with a red circle, f/e)

hmm yeah that does seem reasonable. I was trying to implement a custom auto-suggestions (and learn zsh in the process). I've gotten it to show suggestions and just need to give them some different colours. guess I'll have to look for another way. I'm setting the RBUFFER to contain/update the suggestions on keypress

Glancing through the source of zsh-autosuggestions, it looks like it uses POSTDISPLAY and region_highlight for displaying and styling the suggestion.
